# NotImplementedError: Non-relative patterns are unsupported from attempted looping over all .html files in a directory

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I am trying to loop over all html files in a directory but am getting this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Non-relative patterns are unsupported
```

The code I am using is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse
from pathlib import Path

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = ("Script to scrape data from antismash html output"))

parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", help = "give path/to/directory containing antismash outputs", required = True)

args = parser.parse_args()

for file in Path(args.path).glob("/*.html"):
    def scraper(filename):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), 'html.parser')
        soup.findAll('a') > os.path.basename(filename).txt
```

I have previously used the same method and not gotten an error so I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `/` inside the `glob` call when working with `PathLib`. The correct code would be:

```
for file in Path(args.path).glob("*.html"):
    def scraper(filename):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), 'html.parser')
        soup.findAll('a') > os.path.basename(filename).txt
```